# Submitting iPhone app to a 3rd party

Tags: iphone

Hoping someone will be so kind as to offer some help and i'll gladly try and do the same.

I have got the process for submitting my own iphone apps down pat but submitting for a client to upload to their own account is proving soooo difficult.
Normally I set my apps to 'Release / Distribution in Build Settings, and use my own personal App Store Distrubtion Profile.
But after many failed attempts of archiving and sending in this fashion we've been unable to crack the code on why it always fails when they try to then submit via Application Loader.

They already have the utility ready with the correct bundle ID in iTunesConnect (application loader see's it), but is it simply that I need them to send me a Distribution Profile generated by them? Or do I also need access to their developer credentials?

Worst case/ another option cant I just say no code signing required?

Feels like Im so close but missing a vital piece or two of the puzzle (or my brain :)

Please can someone shine a light and guide me into the harbor?
Any advice greatfully received.

Thanks,

AB.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign the app with your client's App Store distribution provisioning profile. You need the client's distribution certificate to do that (including the private key).

Answer (score 0):

The application needs to be signed with **their** distribution profile, not yours.

Comment: ahh thanks so much guys! One further question, having since down a fair bit of reading I'm led to believe that if they don't want to part with the Distribution Certificate then it will be sufficient for them to make and provide a Dist PROFILE specific to the app (using the bundle ID). Then when I archive and send the release build they can re-sign it and validate using their credentials. Can anyone confirm this will work or done so themselves?  Thanks!!

Comment: @AlfBourke I asked the exact same question in this year's WWDC labs, and the answer was that it's not possible.